# Log Shipping - Determining Rows Modified After a Restore

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

The company I'm doing some work for is using log shipping to sync a production database with a secondary. Is there any way I can determine the rows that were inserted, updated or deleted after a restore is done on the secondary? Since the secondary is read-only, I cannot put triggers on any tables, enable CDC etc. on the secondary. So I'm looking for a way to know what changed after a restore.

SQL Server 2014 is being used.

Comment: do you want to find out changes after the full backup is restored or after a particular t-log backup file is restored ? 2 ways I can think of - if you have last_updated_date column then you can just read from primary or you can use undocumented [fn_dump_dblog](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) - filtering by `LOP_DELETE_ROWS` for deletes, etc. from the backup file itself.

Comment: @Kin - I need to determine all changes after each log backup file restore is done.

Comment: Ok ..  then implement sql auditing on primary and you can scan in the audit logs with the time frame of your tlogs. Else your last approach will be to use `fn_dump_dblog` - read tlog directly using undocumented function and then filter by `LOP_DELETE_ROWS` etc to check for deletes. This will be learning curve for you.